# Matrix dot-product in R

Tags: r, dot-product

I am tring to figure out how to the dot product.

```
b = matrix(1:70, ncol=7)
g= matrix(1:48, ncol=6)
resulta = matrix(0,6,7)
for (c in 1:ncol(b)){
  for (i in 1:ncol(g)){
    resulta[i,c] <- sum((g[,i]) * (b[,c]))
  }
}
```

Warning messages:

```
1: In (g[, i]) * (b[, c]) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In (g[, i]) * (b[, c]) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

...........................Total 42 alike messages

Comment: Sir, you are trying to multiply metrices with different dimensions `10x7` `8x6`. There is 10-element vector times 8-element vector in each loop. Besides, to do this properly, one should to use matrix multiplication operator instead of loop `%*%`. Hope this will help http://my.ilstu.edu/~wjschne/442/MatrixAlgebraInR.html#(1)

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you multiply matrices, you have to make sure that dimensions are such that #columns of first matrix is same as #rows of second i.e. if first matrix is `a x b`, second matrix has to be `b x c` (c and a may or may not be equal) so that the resultant matrix is `a x c`.

In your case, matrix b is `70 x 7` meaning matrix g should be a `7 x something` matrix. In other words, matrix g should have exactly 7 rows.

Once you have fixed the dimensions, try this for quick matrix multiplication:
`resulta <- b %*% g`
`resulta`